# Chef Installing MySQL 5.6 on Centos 7

Tags: centos-7, chef

I'm trying to install specific sub-versions of MySQL via a recipe. I've set the node attribute to 5.6 and ran chef-client on a vagrant test box but it's failing with the following error:

```
==> default: Recipe: my-mysql::default
==> default:   * mysql_service[testdb] action create
==> default:     * mysql_server_installation_package[testdb] action install
==> default:
==> default:       * yum_package[mysql-community-server] action install
==> default:
==> default:         * No candidate version available for mysql-community-server
==> default:
==> default:         ================================================================================
==> default:         Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[mysql-community-server]'
==> default:         ================================================================================
==> default:
==> default:         Chef::Exceptions::Package
==> default:         -------------------------
==> default:         No candidate version available for mysql-community-server
==> default:
==> default:         Resource Declaration:
==> default:         ---------------------
==> default:         # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_server_installation_package.rb
==> default:
==> default:          17:       package package_name do
==> default:          18:         version package_version if package_version
==> default:          19:         options package_options if package_options
==> default:          20:         notifies :install, 'package[perl-Sys-Hostname-Long]', :immediately if platform_family?('suse')
==> default:          21:         notifies :run, 'execute[Initial DB setup script]', :immediately if platform_family?('suse')
==> default:          22:         action :install
==> default:          23:       end
==> default:          24:
==> default:
==> default:         Compiled Resource:
==> default:         ------------------
==> default:         # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/mysql_server_installation_package.rb:17:in `block in <class:MysqlServerInstallationPackage>'
==> default:
==> default:         yum_package("mysql-community-server") do
==> default:           package_name "mysql-community-server"
==> default:           action [:install]
==> default:           retries 0
==> default:           retry_delay 2
==> default:           default_guard_interpreter :default
==> default:           declared_type :package
==> default:           cookbook_name "my-mysql"
==> default:           version "5.6.29-2.el7"
==> default:           flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
==> default:         end
```

My recipe uses the mysql cookbook (currently on 8.0.4). The block in my recipe for setting up mysql is as follows:

```
mysql_service mysql_service_name do
  version node['mysql']['version']
  bind_address node['mysql']['bind_address']
  port node['mysql']['port']
  data_dir node['mysql']['data_dir']
  initial_root_password 'test'
  action [:create, :start]
end
```

I created a custom role (for simplicity) for use with Vagrant Chef provisioning. Here are the default attributes:

```
"default_attributes": {
        "mysql": {
            "version": "5.6",
            "service_name": "testdb"
        }
    },
```

**Does anybody know of working examples of MySQL 5.6/5.7 installed on Centos 7 using Chef?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have correct repo added to your system, take a look at [yum-mysql-community](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/yum-mysql-community) cookbook. You may need to add something like that to your recipe:

```
include_recipe 'yum-mysql-community::mysql57'
```